# Using session storage in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

In my React app's session storage `websiteData` object, I the following values that I am trying to access:

```
websiteData:
conf: type1,
 configuration: 
    linkBackSite: "https://www.webste.com/somePath/"
```

I created a function that should first looks for the session storage item `conf` and if that item matches, return the URL string from configuration.

After that I pass the function into my button's onClick event which would return the user to the relative URL:

```
  const returnToEnv = () => {
    const getConfiguration = sessionStorage.getItem('conf');
    console.log('getConfiguration', getConfiguration);
    if (getConfiguration === 'type1') {
      return JSON.parse(
        sessionStorage.getItem('configuration', 'linkBackSite')
      );
    } else {
      console.log('no');
    }
  };


      <button className="active" onClick={returnToEnv}>
        {i18next.t('CONFIRMATION.return')}
      </button>
```

When I click the button, nothing is happening and the console log is returning null. What is the correct way to access these items inside of the sessionStorage object and use the returned object in the `onClick` event?

Comment: You directly executing the function `returnToEnv` rather than assigning it as event handler. So the function gets executed and the result of the function gets assigned to `onClick`. So the assignment resolves to `onClick=undefined`, which does nothing.
Try this: `onClick={returnToEnv}`

Comment: @Ogod thanks. I actually put that in on accident. The console log still returns "no" from the conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was easier once I understood the configuration:

```
  const websiteData = JSON.parse(
    sessionStorage.getItem('websiteData')
  );

  const linkBackSite = websiteData.configuration.linkBackSite;

      <a href={linkBackSite} alt="">
          {i18next.t('CONFIRMATION.return')}
        </a>
```

After calling the main object in `const websiteData`, I returned the specific key in `const linkBackSite`.

Since it is pointing to a preconfigured public URL, I removed the `onClick` event and put it directly in the HTML anchor element.